# How can I use primary key instead of name in query for fetching data for a particular row?

Tags: android

This code works, but the query is based on name. How can I use primary key instead of name without showing the primary key in listview?

This code is in my database file:

```
public ArrayList<String> data() {
    ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> av = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.query(helper.TABLE_NAME, new String[] {helper.NAME,helper.DATE,helper.PEOPLE}, null, null, null, null,null );
    c.moveToFirst();
    do {
        String db_name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(helper.NAME))+ "       " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(helper.DATE))+"    "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(helper.PEOPLE));
        ar.add(db_name);//only ar will be show in listview
        c.moveToNext();
    } while (!c.isAfterLast());
    return ar;

}
```

and The Activity code is:

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
ar = helper.data();
ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ar);
lv.setAdapter(ad);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String s = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        String k = "";
        String p[] = s.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < p.length-7; i++)
            k = k + " " + p[i];
        k = k.trim();//k contains the name string

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Details.class);
        i.putExtra("name", k);//next activity will fetch all the details with  the help of name.
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: "my code is running perfect" - clearly not.....

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear to me. But if its what I think you want to do, you can try something like this, this fetches a book in the database based on its ID (the primary key)

```
public Book getBook(int id){

// 1. get reference to readable DB
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

// 2. build query
Cursor cursor = 
        db.query(TABLE_BOOKS, // a. table
        COLUMNS, // b. column names
        " id = ?", // c. selections 
        new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, // d. selections args
        null, // e. group by
        null, // f. having
        null, // g. order by
        null); // h. limit

// 3. if we got results get the first one
if (cursor != null)
    cursor.moveToFirst();

// 4. build book object
Book book = new Book();
book.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
book.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
book.setAuthor(cursor.getString(2));

//log 
Log.d("getBook("+id+")", book.toString());

// 5. return book
return book;
}
```

[Source](http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

which was set using:

```
// SQL statement to create book table
    String CREATE_BOOK_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE books ( " +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
            "title TEXT, "+
            "author TEXT )";
```

> How can I use primary key instead of name without showing the primary key in listview?

Aren't you supposed to be in charge of what you show in your `ListView`?

Comment: actually sir this app will use for manage the events/parties.it has 3 paeges.there are 4 edit text on first page name,date,no.of people,menu.from here all the details will be saved in data base.and next page is "booked parties" on this page i have put a listview that will show only name and date.and when i will click on a item i will get all the related details.so when i click on item m getting the item position and thatis name.thats why my next fetching details query is based on name.its create problem for same name.so how can i get primary key instead of name.

Comment: Do you want primary key to be name of event?

Comment: in my code where i.putExtra("name", k); //here k containts the name for get(position). here i want to use the row id of that particula item.but the id should not be shown in listview.